# Is it possible to limit the lines of text displayed in a Sharepoint list view?

Tags: sharepoint

The clearest way to explain this is with an image:

http://i42.tinypic.com/fc1gdk.png

I want to only show the first two lines of the "Solution" field, as otherwise with a long solution, it becomes very hard to browse the list. Is this possible? I've looked at the list and view options, and nothing is apparent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cannot see image, corporate blockage, but for a text column this will work.

Create a new column and make it calculated, make the formula =left("your column",2000) then use the calculated column in your views.

Comment: Thanks, looks great. It would have worked, except formulas can be applied to a "single line of text" datatype, but not multiple lines.

I get this message: 

One or more column references are not allowed, because the columns are defined as a data type that is not supported in formulas.  

For others who are interested, the actual formula should be:
=LEFT([Solution],500) or however many characters you wish to limit.

Comment: You can use a SPD workflow to copy the multi-line to a single line then use the left function onthat column, but you will get HTML in the column; or make a code based workflow.  Change multi-line to plain text if possible  
Other option is the change the display.aspx page so you have a custom  List Form then modify text using xslt, but even then you have the change of removing the ending tags of the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it, and yes it's a little complicated:

First, create a single-line text column, I'll call it Content

Second, create a calculated column, I'll call it ContentCalc, set the formula to =[Content]

Third, delete the first column Content, then recreate it as a multi-line text column

Fourth, create a third column, I'll call it Summary, and set the formula to =LEFT([ContentCalc],60), with 60 being any number of chars you want to truncate it to

Finally, to get rid of the  stuff, insert the following source into a Content Editor Web Part placed under the list:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var theTDs = document.getElementsByTagName("TD");
  var i=0;
  var TDContent = " ";
  while (i < theTDs.length)
  {
    try
    {
      TDContent = theTDs[i].innerText || theTDs[i].textContent;
      if (TDContent.indexOf("<div") == 0)
        {
          theTDs[i].innerHTML = TDContent;
        }
    }
  catch(err){}
  i=i+1;
  }
</script>
```

I got the bulk of this from this link, but I had to mod the instructions a little, and it still took a while to implement exactly right.

Then, if you want to keep the Calc columns from displaying in the Display form, you'll have to create a custom form.

NOTE: This javascript doesn't work for Extended Rich Text because it affects after the truncation, and the div tag is too long for the amount I was truncating. By extending the amount of chars in my truncation I was able to get it to work mostly. There are still some edge cases I haven't figured out completely yet.

Comment: Use this calculated definition for the Summary column : =IF(LEN(ContentCalc)>57,LEFT(ContentCalc,60)&"...</div>",ContentCalc)

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread but just in case someone stumbles on to it looking for help...there is a much easier way to accomplish this via html code. 
When viewing your list, edit page.  Add Web Part: Content and Media > script editor and paste the following code.

```
<style type="text/css">
.ms-vb2 .ms-rtestate-field {
max-width: 250px;
max-height: 38px;
overflow: hidden;
}

.ms-vb2 .ms-rtestate-field:hover {
max-height: none;
}
</style>
<h2>
</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Expand collapse trick as stated in : http://salaudeen.blogspot.com/2010/07/expand-collapse-for-multiline-text.html